# Is there a python function that creates a transition table of two pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

My dataframe is built up as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[good, good, bad, perfect, good], [perfect, good, perfect, good, good]]),
               columns=['after', 'before'])
```

What I want is to create a table/matrix that displays the transitions from before to after something like this:
[how table should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Epx.png)

I do not know the correct term for such a table/matrix and I'm having a hard time finding anything about it online. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by all possible unique values:

```
a = np.unique(df.to_numpy())
df = pd.crosstab(df['before'], df['after']).reindex(columns=a, index=a, fill_value=0)
print (df)
after    bad  good  perfect
before                     
bad        0     0        0
good       0     2        1
perfect    1     1        0
```